# How to set the default value of datafield - EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, datefield

```
var startdt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
    name: 'startdt',
    id: 'startdt',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    endDateField: 'enddt', // id of the end date field
    value = new date()
    })

var enddt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    name: 'enddt',
    id: 'enddt',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    startDateField: 'startdt', // id of the start date field
    value = new date()
    })
```

this kind of method will let the window unable to show in center correctly.
any idea to let the datefield set the default value with out using this method?

Comment: You typed value = new date() but you should type value: new Date(). Change the = with a :

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is an bug from extjs 4,u can try this following code

```
var startdt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
    name: 'startdt',
    id: 'startdt',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    endDateField: 'enddt', // id of the end date field
    listeners : {
    render : function(datefield) {
        /// code to convert GMT String to date object
        datefield.setValue(new Date());
                }
        }
    })

    var enddt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    name: 'enddt',
    id: 'enddt',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    startDateField: 'startdt', // id of the start date field
    listeners : {
    render : function(datefield) {
        /// code to convert GMT String to date object
        datefield.setValue(new Date());
                }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

try it like this:

```
var startdt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
    name: 'startdt',
    id: 'startdt',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    endDateField: 'enddt', // id of the end date field
    value: new Date()
    })

var enddt = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    name: 'enddt',
    id: 'enddt',
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    startDateField: 'startdt', // id of the start date field
    value: new Date()
    })
```